# Conserve header while joining files in bash

Tags: awk

I have this 2 tab separated files:

fileA.tsv

```
probeId    sample1_betaval    sample2_betaval    sample3_betaval
   a              1                  2                  3
   b              4                  5                  6
   c              7                  8                  9
```

fileB.tsv

```
probeId       region      gene
   a         intronic      tp53
   b         non-coding     NA 
   c         exonic         kras
```

As they are already sorted by probeId, I've merged both files:

```
join -j 1 fileA.tsv fileB.tsv -t $'\t' > complete.tsv
```

The problem is that the output does not conserve headers:

```
   a              1                  2                  3           intronic    tp53
   b              4                  5                  6           non-coding   NA
   c              7                  8                  9            exonic      kras
```

While my desired output is:

```
probeId    sample1_betaval    sample2_betaval    sample3_betaval     region     gene
   a              1                  2                  3           intronic    tp53
   b              4                  5                  6           non-coding   NA
   c              7                  8                  9            exonic      kras
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `--header` option if your join provides it:

```
join --header -j 1 fileA.tsv fileB.tsv -t $'\t' > complete.tsv
```

Comment: I was looking to solve the same problem and this option keeps the header, but not on the top on the file, how to keep it on the top?

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following(in case you are ok with it).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  array[$1]=$0
  next
}
($1 in array){
  print array[$1],$2,$3
}
'  filea  fileb | column -t
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** In case OP has many columns in fileb and want to print all apart from 1st column then try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  array[$1]=$0
  next
}
($1 in array){
  val=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  print array[val],$0
}
'  filea  fileb | column -t
```

Comment: what should I do if my filea actually has 500 columns?

Comment: @Jeni, in fileb you mean? And you want all columns from fileb apart from 1st column?

Comment: @Jeni This is working. If you could have more columns, you should mention it in your question.

Comment: I get this output: `column: line 1 is too long, output will be truncated`

Comment: @Jeni, I am sorry no idea on this one, with shown samples it worked fine for me.